# Hats can block page controls

Tags: bug, status-declined, winter-bash-2020

Depending on how a user places his hat it may become hard to impossible to click e.g. the "Activity" button on a users profile-page - like e.g. here:

[image]

When trying to click the visible part of "Activity" I always end up on that users hat-list.

Comment: I'd say this is by-design

Comment: @Luuklag preventing users from accessing available controls seems like shitty design to me...

Comment: That's the hat, size, and position you choose, resize, move, or choose a different hat for that site. A better complaint of this type is where [you can't move the hat, and it partly blocks a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMRZX.jpg) - that takes careful tapping on a touchscreen.

Comment: cross site dupe: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403735/how-can-i-see-a-milliners-activity

Comment: @Rob If it's your own profile you can replace the hat, but if you are trying to get to another user's Activity page, you can't change their hat.

Comment: @Eran (and two others), it has been declined. After searching for any dupes you can ask how to get a decision reconsidered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are restrictions put in place that — while allowing hats to go out of the borders of the profile — are intended to prevent them from going *too* out of bounds. Looks like some of the hats this year are able to violate that guideline.

However, I do not think that I am going to be able to get to fixing this in time to make a difference this year (and to really fix it would require not only changing the wear-hat customization tool, but to also detect currently-worn hats that are out of bounds and somehow fix them something that is definitely out of scope for this event that will be ending in a couple of weeks).

So going to decline this one - even in cases where the link is blocked, part of it is almost always still accessible (and there are other ways of getting to /activity if you really need it).

> hat is blocking link
> this makes me sad, but oh well…
> not gonna happen

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I didn't really expect some change to happen before 6-8 weeks, which is well after the end of this year's hat-season. But perhaps something to keep in mind for next year.