# Hat list kinda blocks off link to meta site

Tags: bug, winter-bash

[image]

As you can see, the "Meta user" is very close to the hat list and, sometimes, when I'm visiting the meta, I accidentally click on the hat list. Is this by design or a bug?

Comment: Don't worry it will all be over soon.

Comment: like..... on Jan 4?

Comment: To be fair, this is annoying when moderating too.. if the username is short enough, that hat thing will decrease the hitbox on the numbers that are quick links to a users flagged posts or previous mod messages significantly.

Comment: I've found this quite annoying. For me (Firefox on Linux if that's relevant) the overlap is worse than the image above: note the obscured link text and the pointer location/tooltip in this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/QxUefvE).

Comment: Confirmed, first [mentioned here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358043/hats-can-block-page-controls#comment1195970_358043) in a comment on a Question  about adjusting one's hat so it's deliberately disruptive.